# PHP-EWS library and autoload classes

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to use `PHP-EWS` library, to make a connection with Exchange.
So I declared two libraries like this :

```
function mymodule_libraries_info() {
    $libraries = array(
        'php-ews-master' => array(
            'name' => 'php-ews-master',
            'vendor url' => 'https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/',
            'download url' => 'https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/archive/master.zip',
            'version callback' => 'mymodule_callback',
            'files' => array(
                'php' => array(
                    //Main classes
                    'src/Client.php',
                    'src/ClassMap.php',
                    'src/Autodiscover.php',
                    'src/Type.php',
                    'src/ArrayType.php',
                    'src/Request.php',
                    'src/Enumeration.php',
                    'src/Response.php',
                    //Others classes
                    //'src/Request/BaseRequestType.php',
                    'src/Request/FindItemType.php',
                    'src/Request/FindItemType.php' => array('autoload' => TRUE),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        //Soap connection
        'php-ntlm' => array(
            'name' => 'php-ntlm',
            'vendor url' => 'https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ntlm/',
            'download url' => 'https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ntlm/archive/master.zip',
            'version callback' => 'mymodule_callback',
            'files' => array(
                'php' => array(
                    'src/SoapClient.php',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    return $libraries;
}
```

Next, in a custom function, I used the main function to connect my user :

```
//Load libraries
libraries_load('php-ntlm');
libraries_load('php-ews-master');

$timezone = 'Eastern Standard Time';
$email = 'myuser.onmicrosoft.com';
$pass = 'mypass';
$client = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client('outlook.office365.com', $email, $pass);
$client->setTimezone($timezone);
```

My first question is, why I need to use the full namespace `\jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client` to use the class and not just `Client` ?
After the connection I want to get all events from the calendar of this user. So the first class used is `\jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\FindItemType`. I put it in my library files and used it, but I got this error :

`Fatal error: Class 'jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\BaseRequestType' not found in /usr/share/myapp/sites/all/libraries/php-ews-master/src/Request/FindItemType.php on line 14`

I got this error because the class `\jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\FindItemType` extends another class `BaseRequestType`

```
class FindItemType extends BaseRequestType
```

Why, when I included the class `\jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\FindItemType` aren't the classes loaded or extends in this class not loaded ?
In the librarie, there is a class called `ClassMap.php` which list all classes used by the library, there is maybe a way to use this class to load all classes ?

I tried to use this librarie out of drupal with `composer` and `autoload.php`. And I just need to call this, and it works :

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Client; 
use \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\FindItemType;
```

So maybe in drupal I don't have this autoload which load automatically all the classes used ?
I tried a lot of things but for the moment, It's work when I call all the classes one by one in my files declarations in the librarie, but the array is too big...

Thank you if you can help me

Comment: My problem isn't solved. If someone have an idea ? I tried to use X autoload module like this in my HOOK_libraries_infos : `'xautoload' => function($adapter) { $adapter->namespaceRoot('jamesiarmes\PhpEws', 'src'); },` but it's not working...